# SML/NJ - about ":=" operator

Tags: sml, smlnj

I did some checks on `:=` operator and I want to make sure that I got it well  .

let -

```
val r1 = ref 1 ;  (* !r1 = 1 *)
val r2 = ref 2 ;  (* !r2 = 2 *)
val r3 = ref 3 ;  (* !r3 = 3 *)

r1 := !r2 ; (* !r1 = 2 *)
r2 := !r3 ; (* !r2 = 3 *)
!r1 ;  (* still !r1 = 2 *)
```

Apparently I thought that  `r2 := !r3 ;` would cause to `!r1` value to change too , which didn't occurred  , so it seems that `r1 := !r2 ;` does not points `r1` to same address as `r2`  ,but just allocate new memory for `!r1` and set the `2` value there  .

Am I right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assignment does not allocate new memory. After `r1 := !r2`, the reference `r1` "points" to the value `2` taken from `r2`, not to `r2` itself. Consequently, updating `r2` later does not affect it.

If you want such an effect, then you have to use another indirection, e.g. an `int ref ref` type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `r1` and `r2` were initialized to point to different data structures. The `:=` operator simply changes the value of the ref structure pointed to by the left side. If you want `r1` and `r2` to point to the same ref structure, you could have not defined `r1` initially, and then later defined it like `val r1 = r2`. It is impossible to assign to a variable in ML after it is initially defined.